# How to parse the JSON which is invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios8, ios9

I am working on a iOS project where I have come across the web service which returns the invalid JSON.

The Android guy have already parsed it but I am not being able to parse it.
Can anyone help.

I am posting the JSON response below:

> [{MemberId:"-9223372036854775467",MemberType:"A",FirstName:"Vasant",MiddleName:"",LastName:"Patil",MobileNo:"8378990844",Designation:"",Department:"",JoiningYear:"2009",CourseId:"-9223372036854775808",ProfilePhoto:"123.jpg",InstituteId:"",CurrentLocation:"Pune",EmailIdAsUserName:"True",CoverPhoto:"",InsertDate:"9/21/2015 4:37:07 AM",InsertBy:"dbo586494821",UpdateDate:"",UpdateBy:"",EmailId:"vasant@noeticsystems.co.in",UserId:"",FullName:"Vasant  Patil",SiteStatus:"Email",Password:"v",BranchId:"",IsDelete:"N",DateofBirth:"6/11/1983 12:00:00 AM",State:"Maharashtra",Country:"India",Gender:"Male",MemberDay:"21",MemberMonth:"9",MemberYear:"2015",AdminApproved:"True",MobileNo1:"8378990844",EmailId1:"vasant@noeticsystems.co.in",AdminApproved1:"True",CourseName:"B.E",Branch:"",Designation1:"",Organization:"",BranchYear:"2009-2013"}]

Comment: "How to parse the JSON which is invalid" – you don't, you walk up to the backend guy and tell him to fix his JSON response.

Comment: "I have come across the web service" sounds like the OP doesn't have that kind of influence over the service, @The.

Comment: @JoshCaswell right, but he could still use some form of bug reporting, maintenance, customer support, etc. That would be *the* proper way of resolving this issue.

Comment: Service can not be changed as website and android app is already working. Is there any way to parse this kind of JSON or making it a valid JSON in objective c itself? @TheParamagneticCroissant

Comment: @Nilesh you could try using JavaScriptCore to evaluate the string as it *seems* to be a valid JavaScript object, but… that's dull at best.

Comment: Just tell the web developer it is invalid JSON and needs to be fixed. Do that via email with a copy to his manager. That the iPhone project will not move forward until the JSON is corrected and the correction is easy. That there will be future roadblocks due to invalid JSON. Point them to [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org) and [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are no quotes around the key strings, the JSON is invalid.

That can be fixed rather easily with a regular expression and

Here is the [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org) site, JSON is very simple.

You can use an online [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com) to find out exactly what the problem is.

Here is the output from trying to validate the JSON in the question:

```
Parse error on line 2:
[    {        MemberId: "-92233720
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Here is the corrected JSON just to demonstrate the fix works:

```
[
    {
        "MemberId": "-9223372036854775467",
        "MemberType": "A",
        "FirstName": "Vasant",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "Patil",
        "MobileNo": "8378990844",
        "Designation": "",
        "Department": "",
        "JoiningYear": "2009",
        "CourseId": "-9223372036854775808",
        "ProfilePhoto": "123.jpg",
        "InstituteId": "",
        "CurrentLocation": "Pune",
        "EmailIdAsUserName": "True",
        "CoverPhoto": "",
        "InsertDate": "9/21/2015 4:37:07 AM",
        "InsertBy": "dbo586494821",
        "UpdateDate": "",
        "UpdateBy": "",
        "EmailId": "vasant@noeticsystems.co.in",
        "UserId": "",
        "FullName": "Vasant Patil",
        "SiteStatus": "Email",
        "Password": "v",
        "BranchId": "",
        "IsDelete": "N",
        "DateofBirth": "6/11/1983 12:00:00 AM",
        "State": "Maharashtra",
        "Country": "India",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "MemberDay": "21",
        "MemberMonth": "9",
        "MemberYear": "2015",
        "AdminApproved": "True",
        "MobileNo1": "8378990844",
        "EmailId1": "vasant@noeticsystems.co.in",
        "AdminApproved1": "True",
        "CourseName": "B.E",
        "Branch": "",
        "Designation1": "",
        "Organization": "",
        "BranchYear": "2009-2013"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you help making it a valid JSON using regular expression or anything else @zaph

Comment: SO is about helping developers with their code, you need to make a best effort and if you have problems post the code. See ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)
for help with the regular expression. But there a saying: "I had one problem, I tried to solve it with a regular expression, now I have two problems". Or choose another method.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this needs to be done in iOS code.

Otherwise, you may try this out:

http://www.fixjson.com